# I chose to download the 32-bit version, but it downloads the 64-bit version instead. Why?

Tags: installation, 12.10, 64-bit, downloads, 32-bit

I had it installed and running last night, but I could tell it wasn't 32-bit cause when installing the Adobe Flash player, it said I had a 64-bit OS. I uninstalled it, then downloaded it again, then installed it again, but it's saying that this is the filename: ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent

Why? I want the correct version.

Comment: I wouldn't trust the Adobe Flash Player installer to tell me what OS I have. Type in `uname -a` in terminal and add the output to your post.

Comment: I did that too, and it said it was 64 bit.

Comment: Well, considering your comments below, you have 64-bit processor. Might as well go with the 64-bit Ubuntu installation you have now :)

Answer (score 0):

the "AMD64" is the 64 bit version. If you have a 64 bit processor there is, IMO, no good reason to run the 32 bit version.

If, however, you still wish to run the 32 bit version anyways, download the 32 bit iso from any mirror.

http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/ubuntu-iso/CDs/quantal/

You want the "i386" iso

http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/ubuntu-iso/CDs/quantal/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso

Comment: I don't have a 32-bit processor though cause my Windows is only 32 bit.

Comment: IMO, you can/should install the 64 bit version of Ubuntu regardless of the Windows version.